# Quorum Account existence on node requirement of Private Transaction

Tags: transactions, nodes, quorum

I am trying out private transaction using Quorum.
Two quorum nodes N1 and N2 configured to participate in the private transaction.

I deployed a contract which is private for N1 and N2.

I issue transaction (invoke contract method) using A1 account (address) and use public key of N2 node.  Note that account A1 is not present on either of the nodes N1/N2.

I connect to Node N1 to issue the transaction.

I receive following error when the transaction is sent to the N1 node.

```
Error processing transaction request: account is locked
```

I do not get such an error in following scenario:

1. Deploy public contract
2. Issue transaction (invoke contract method) using A1 account (address) by connecting to node N1

Im using web3j-quorum API to connect to the quorum nodes.

Please help to have the issue resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
S

Comment: you may need to unlock an account first with `web3.personal.unlockAccount(account,password)`

Comment: Tried unlocking the account.  Didn't help :(

Comment: any error message displayed?

Comment: No error in geth log.
Following is stack trace received in DApp
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: account is locked
...
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: account is locked
 at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.processResponse(TransactionManager.java:61)
 at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.executeTransaction

Comment: Just observed following: If i copy A1 account file on the node N1, Transaction could complete successfully.  I did not understand why this happened.  Since, this is not needed if I perform public transaction.  Please help me to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As the doc says:

> Note that if Party A does not receive a response/receives a Nack from Party B then the Transaction will not be propagated to the network. It is a prerequisite for the recipients to store the communicated payload

https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Transaction-Processing

I think one node that knows about account A needs to store the private state